# Opening a preexisting Form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a Main Form. After clicking a button on the Main Form I want another preexisting Form to open. I have already arranged it so the preexisting form will *not* open when the program is initially run.

Comment: Preexisting in your app, or external to your app?

Comment: In my app.. It (Form1) is in the same folder as Form2 and I can access some methods from Form1, but not .Show()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.Show();
```

Comment: How would you define a *pre-existing* form? Can you show some code, or at least a list of files in your solution?

Comment: I have Form1 and Form2.. You can call some methods of Form2 from Form1's code, but not Show()..

Comment: @StevenFontaine Add a method to Form1 that's public, which calls FOrm1.Show()...  essentially wrapping the method.

Comment: I have tried that and, unless I did it wrong, didn't work. (and it's Form2 that I want to show. I assume you meant Form2 rather that Form1?)

Comment: @StevenFontaine You need to create an instance of `Form2` to be able to show the form. You cannot call `Form2.Show()` directly. Use the code in my answer.

Comment: Alright.. Is there anyway I can take all the settings and children of Form2 and apply them to the newly instanced Form?

Comment: @StevenFontaine I am not really sure what you meant by that. Do you mean the controls?

Comment: Do you create an instance of Form2 anywhere in your code? I'm suspecting the "some methods" that you can call may be static, and although you have the class Form2, you have no instance of it...